# Undefined symbols for architecture i386: "_PerformXMLXPathQuery"

Tags: iphone, ios

I looked at all the others that had a similar title but none of those solutions worked for some reason...   Hoping someone can help!

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_PerformXMLXPathQuery", referenced from:
      -[WeatherForecast connectionDidFinishLoading:] in WeatherForecast.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

"_PerformXMLXPathQuery", referenced from:
      -[WeatherForecast connectionDidFinishLoading:] in WeatherForecast.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I am new to iOS so any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: just select iphone siulator version from your schemes just next to the run button and then run it...

Comment: Hum... What do I need to do to get different versions?  I currently only have 5.1 and nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are compiling for the simulator (i386) with a library for the Device (ARM). Either compile for the device and run on it or get an i386 version of the library and run with it on the simulator.

Comment: How do I get i386 version of the library?

Comment: @ScottF. where did you get the ARM version from?

Comment: Dunno... Came with what i downloaded I guess?  Like I said, very new to iOS and downloaded Xcode and everything recently so I don't have many extras yet.

Comment: Thank you @Binyamin. I've encountering and fixing a few of these issues lately without knowing why I was compiling for i386 in the first place. Simulator!

Answer (score 1):

For those who need it, the issue was that my XPathQuery.m file was not in the Complied Sources list.  It was as simple as that!

Just posting this for future reference!  Hope it helps someone!